# Send and upload files with php and phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I can't understand how to make a file from my contact form loaded and sent. I tried to search on github, but I can't understand in which part of my code I have to insert it and what I have to insert. 
This is the final part of the html script.
I tried to do it this way, but now it just sends me an empty file.
Thanks everyone for the help

```js
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome-locale"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$indirizzo = $_POST["indirizzo"];
$civico = $_POST["civico"];
$citta = $_POST["citta"];
$provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
$cap = $_POST["cap"];
$newsletters = $_POST["newsletters"];
$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));






$body = "<br>nome-locale:" . $nome .  
       "<br>Email:" . $email .   
       "<br>TelefonoLocale:" . $telefono . 
     "<br>Indirizzo:" . $indirizzo . 
       "<br>Civico:" . $civico . 
     "<br>Città:" . $citta. 
     "<br>Provincia:" . $provincia .
     "<br>Cap:" . $cap . 
    "<br>newsletters:" . $newsletters;


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;



require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'xxxx';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'xxxx';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxx';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('xxxxxx', $name);
    $mail->addAddress('xxxxxxx');     // Add a recipient
    
    
  // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
 
 
   
    
 

    $mail->send();
    echo '<script>
 alert("Messaggio inviato correttamente");
 window.history.go(-1);
 </script>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

```html
<div class="form-group was-validated ">
                   <label class="control-label" name="userfile" enctype="multipart/form-data">Menu1</label>
                <input type="file"  required>
  
</div>
      <div class="form-group was-validated ">
                   <label class="control-label">Menu2</label>
                <input type="file"  required>
   
     <hr>
     <div class="form-group was-validated  ">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3" >
   <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlValidation1"  required>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation1" ><small>Dichiaro di aver letto, accettato e di concordare con le <a href="https://www.google.it/" target="_blank" >Clausole Generali e l'Informativa sulla privacy.</a> Vaimenu.it permette ai locali e agli ospiti di comunicare tramite Vaimenu.it, che riceve ed elabora le comunicazioni in conformità con l'Informativa sulla privacy e le Clausole Generali di xxxx.</small></label>

       </div>
   
      <div class="form-group was-validated  ">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3" >
   <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlValidation2"  checked>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation2" name="newsletters" ><small>Voglio iscrivermi alla newsletter per ricevere promozioni ed altre comunicazione da parte di xxxxx</small></label>

      </div>
         
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg fa-pull-right" type="submit">Finito!<img src="img/star.svg" style="top: auto"></button>
```

Comment: Look at the send uploaded file example in the examples folder on github. It shows you exactly what to do.

Comment: ok, I have seen the example of php mailer, but I can't understand how to integrate it. if I have to make a new .php file or I have to integrate it into my existing file where there is my server data

Comment: The only thing you need to do to make it "integrate" with your existing HTML form is to make sure the field names you've used are the same in your form and the script. I spotted a bug in your form: your input fields have no `name` attribute; that means they will not be submitted when you submit the form, so your input superglobals (`$_POST` etc) will be empty. It might be easier to insert your client-side validation features into the PHPMailer example form than to adapt it the other way around.

Comment: To be clear, [this is the example I mean](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: ok thanks, but what I can't understand the link you sent me contains a php code. but where should I put that code? do I have to create a new file or can I integrate it in my file where there is all the data of the smtp server. and if I have to put it in my file, I can't understand how and where.

Comment: The same place your existing code is? It's basically doing the same thing as your existing code, so either pick out the bits that handle the file upload properly and change your existing script, or change the field names, body creation etc in the PHPMailer example. Your call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this HTML is only a part of your form, right?
Asking as I cannot see any elements to input `email` `telefono` `cap` and few others.

Other thing is that this:

```html
<label class="control-label" name="userfile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

is generally invalid - i mean: the attribute `enctype` here is pointless, it actually should go to the `<form>` element (since you are saying that your form sends files the I assume it actually works just the file issue is the problem).

The main problem which you have here is how you handle the uploaded file:

```
$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
```

If you try this code (for learning):

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['my-file'])) {
    var_dump($_FILES['my-file']);
    var_dump(tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['my-file']['name'])));
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type='file' name='my-file'>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

you will notice (after file upload) something like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(21) "flight_to_hamburg.pdf"
  ["type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpS2dWIg"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(76044)
}
string(75) "/tmp/ecb918e45ff9059a9ad1b7b52c5c0d24575f8ac19474f2f13c908801eafaa48bLMlIeG"
```

which clearly shows you that `sha256` is not what PHP uses for creating names of the temporary files.

Since PHP Mailer allows pointing to a file and sending it under a different name then in my example it would be simply:

```
$path = $_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']; //actual path to the file
$name = $_FILES['my-file']['name']; //actual name of the file
$mail->addAttachment($path, $name);
```

If you want to store the file locally after sending it be sure to also call `move_uploaded_file` as if not then the file will be lost.

So in your example it would be:

```php
$path = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; //actual path to the file
$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; //actual name of the file
$mail->addAttachment($path, $name);
```

if you want to HASH the name of the file for some reason do it on the `$name` variable; `$path` must lead to an existing file.

Also if you do not have any JavaScript which creates `FormData` on submit and sending the file using just standard browser's handling of forms then BE SURE to change ONE of your:

```
<input type="file"  required>
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" required>
```

**name** must match: that is how PHP identifies what data was sent from which fields of the HTML forms.

Comment: This code is unsafe. Better to refer to the example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: ok, I have seen the example of php mailer, but I can't understand how to integrate it. if I have to make a new .php file or I have to integrate it into my existing file where there is my server data

Comment: Because it trusts the contents of `$_FILES` directly, without validating it first, as [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) recommend.

Comment: Basically @Synchro means that you should verify if fields are actually set (if data is being set) before trying to parse it / pass it. Check how `isset` works - for instance if `isset($_FILES['your-file']) === false` then you should not try to attach it with PHP Mailer or execute any actions on it. While learning PHP it is good to make all notices and errors visible to make code as explicit as possible.

Comment: No, that's not it - you *must* use the built-in validators for the `$_FILES` superglobal, which are `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()`, as the docs say. Checking that they exist is good too, but that's not what's unsafe here; maliciously injected values will pass a check that only uses `isset`.

Comment: `$_POST` values should be first filtered for unwanted contents - like often html tags or any javascript inside (`strip_tags`); fields with `email` should be validated against a rule which checks if address is even valid (`filter_var` for instance); other fields checked at least if are not empty. If you add to the database something then using bound parameters.

Comment: Well `is_uploaded_file` cannot harm and correct in terms of intentions, yet its importance is a bit exaggerated here by @Synchro as same security checks are actually first executed within `move_uploaded_file` - reference `if (!SG(rfc1867_uploaded_files)) {` in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L3295 / also in older releases: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/ext/standard/basic_functions.c